# Vagrant - warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777

Tags: macos, permissions, vagrant

Os X Yosemite
10.10.1

i install vagrant and after vagrant status i recieved warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777

`chmod -R o-w /usr/local/` - don't work for me
and

`chmod -R go-w /usr/local` - don't work for me

Answer (score 0):

You need root access to change permissions of any directory except for your home-directory and in Apple OS X, root access is disabled by default, try the steps:

> - Enable root : [Apple support site - steps to enable root access.](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT1528)
> - Change to root user: *su - root* and then try running your *chmod* commands on /usr directory to change permissions

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$sudo chmod -R o-w /usr/local
```

If that doesn't work then try the option "Repair Disk Permissions" from the disk utility.

[image]